# How to put a delay on each loop animation in css3?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to stop a loop animation for a duration, at the end.

```
animation: 6s linear 2s infinite;
```

I've tried to put animation delay for 2 second with css3 shorthanded animation properties but it didn't worked.

How to achivhe this ?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

**Edit:**
This method solved my problem: [stackoverflow.com/a/32223950/1428241](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32223950/1428241)

Comment: For the question asked in title - no, `animation-delay` doesn't work that way. You would have to manually introduce the delay by tweaking the keyframe settings. Have a look at this thread for details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223835/repeat-animation-every-3-seconds/32223950#32223950. It is a very similar question.

Comment: @Harry thats cool mate, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Calling the keyframe via animation:

animation:keyFrameName 6s infinite;
-webkit-animation:keyFrameName 6s infinite;
-moz-animation:keyFrameName 6s infinite;
-o-animation:keyFrameName 6s infinite;


Making a delay for animation:

animation-delay:2s;
-webkit-animation-delay:2s;
-moz-animation-delay:2s;
-o-animation-delay:2s;
```

That should be set in each animation class or id that you have an animation on

Comment: I might mis understood your question, your trying to make a animation stop at some point from infinite to 1?

Comment: hi mate, there is no animation delay in your example /:

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can stop an animation with CSS alone. But you can use JS to change the class attribute to a class without animation after a while.

```
var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
setTimeout(function(){ element.className = 'newClass'; }, 2000);
```

EDIT: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Nillervision/8ncgs94k/

Answer (score 0):

Think you're just missing the animation name.

```css
li {
           /* name, dur, func, delay, iterations */
    animation: woohoo 2s linear 3s infinite
}
li:last-child {
    animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes woohoo {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%; 
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
ul { max-width: 90%; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
  <li>sit amet</li> 
  <li>consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
  <li>Earum deleniti itaque</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: will thanks for the effort but your animation does not have animation delay property /: