# Infinite fade lines with reverse direction

Tags: css, css-animations

I have three spans with border at the bottom and need it fade in and fade out from top to bottom and reverse direction.
It working fine if I have 2 iterations count but with infinite not working properly.

```css
.line {
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid #333;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  width: 1.5em;
}
.lines span[class='line']:nth-child(1) {
  animation: 1.5s ease-in-out 0.2s 2 alternate fade_line;
}
.lines span[class='line']:nth-child(2) {
  animation: 1s ease-in-out 0.7s 2 alternate fade_line;
}
.line {
  animation: 0.5s ease-in-out 1.2s 2 alternate fade_line;
}
@keyframes fade_line {
  0%, 50% {
    border-bottom: 0.2em solid #333;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    border-bottom: 0.2em solid #ddd;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lines">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/70w8mLq4)

Comment: I am a bit lost on how to fix this but the reason for the problem is because of how `animation-delay` works. The delay is added only for the first time. So the animations overlap. You may find [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223835/repeat-animation-every-3-seconds/32223950#32223950) a bit helpful in finding a solution.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to fix that animation of yours but [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/70w8mLq4/3/) is a piece of code that produces something similar. Not sure if it is of any help to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the animation is that the `animation-delay` actually applies only to the first iteration of an animation. The below is an explanation of why it works when there are only 2 iterations and why it doesn't when there are infinite iterations.

**Why does it work when there are only 2 iterations?**

- First `span` starts its animation at `0.2s` (after `animation-delay`). Between `0.2s` to `1.7s`, the border color goes from `#333` to `#ddd` (at `0.95s` which is `50%` of `1.5s` duration to be precise) and between `1.7s` and `3.2s` it goes back (reverse direction) from `#ddd` to `#333` (at `2.45s` to be precise).
- Second `span` starts its animation at `0.7s`. Between `0.7s` to `1.7s`, the border color goes from `#333` to `#ddd` (at `1.2s` to be precise) and between `1.7s` to `2.7s` it goes back (reverse) from `#ddd` to `#333` (at `2.2s` to be precise).
- Third `span` starts its animation at `1.2s`. Between `1.2s` to `1.7s`, the border color goes from `#333` to `#ddd` (at `1.45s` to be precise) and between `1.7s` to `2.2s` it goes back (reverse) from `#ddd` to `#333` (at `1.95s` to be precise).

```
Element         | Iteration 1       | Iteration 2
---------------------------------------------------
First Span      | 0.95s             | 2.45s
Second Span     | 1.2s              | 2.2s
Third Span      | 1.45s             | 1.95s
```

As you can see, there is a nice flow to it as far as there are only 2 iterations.

---

**Why does it not work when the iteration count is set to infinite?**

Now lets see what happens with the third and subsequent iterations:

- First `span` - Between `3.2s` to `4.7s`, the border color goes from `#333` to `#ddd` (at `3.95s` to be precise) and between `4.7s` and `6.2s` it goes back (reverse) from `#ddd` to `#333` (at `5.45s` to be precise).
- Second `span` - Between `2.7s` to `3.7s` the border color goes from `#333` to `#ddd` (at `3.2s` to be precise) and between `3.7s` to `4.7s` it goes back (reverse) from `#ddd` to `#333` (at `4.2s` to be precise).
- Third `span` - Between `2.2s` to `2.7s` the border color goes from `#333` to `#ddd` (at `2.45s` to be precise) and between `2.7s` to `3.2s` it goes back (reverse) from `#ddd` to `#333` (at `2.95s` to be precise).

```
Element         | Iteration 1       | Iteration 2       | Iteration 3       | Iteration 4
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
First Span      | 0.95s             | 2.45s             | 3.95s             | 5.45s
Second Span     | 1.2s              | 2.2s              | 3.2s              | 4.2s
Third Span      | 1.45s             | 1.95s             | 2.45s             | 2.95s
```

As you can see the flow is completely messed up because the animations start to overlap due to the way the animation duration and delay are configured.

---

**Solutions:**

Generally, the approach for introducing a delay between each iteration of an infinite loop animation is to modify the keyframes such that they add an equal delay for every iteration. I had explained this in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223835/repeat-animation-every-3-seconds/32223950#32223950). Unfortunately, your case is a lot more complex due to reverse animation. I couldn't modify the keyframes to match your expectation but I hope you'd find the abov explanation helpful in understanding the issue.

If you are happy to use alternate methods to achieve the same effect then you could have a look at `linear-gradient` background images to create the hamburger effect and then add animation to it.

```css
.lines {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#333, #333), linear-gradient(#333, #333), linear-gradient(#333, #333);
  background-size: 100% 5px;
  background-position: 0px 5px, 0px 15px, 0px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: bars 1.7s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes bars {
  0% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#333, #333), linear-gradient(#333, #333), linear-gradient(#333, #333);
  }
  33% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ddd, #ddd), linear-gradient(#333, #333), linear-gradient(#333, #333);
  }
  66% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ddd, #ddd), linear-gradient(#ddd, #ddd), linear-gradient(#333, #333);
  }
  100% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ddd, #ddd), linear-gradient(#ddd, #ddd), linear-gradient(#ddd, #ddd);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="lines"></div>
```

Below is a solution using your initial approach (kindly contributed by [vals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1926369/vals)). But you can't reuse the keyframes!

```css
.line {
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid #333;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  width: 1.5em;
}
.line {
  animation: 1.7s ease-in-out infinite alternate fade_line1;
}
.line:nth-child(2) {
  animation-name: fade_line2;
}
.line:nth-child(3) {
  animation-name: fade_line3;
}
@keyframes fade_line1 { /* use 25% instead of 30% if the splits need to be equal among all 3 */
  0%, 30% {
    border-bottom-color: #333;
  }
  30%, 100% {
    border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  }
}
@keyframes fade_line2 {
  0%, 50% {
    border-bottom-color: #333;
  }
  50%, 100% {
    border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  }
}
@keyframes fade_line3 { /* use 75% instead of 70% if the splits need to be equal among all 3 */
  0%, 70% {
    border-bottom-color: #333;
  }
  70%, 100% {
    border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="lines">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="line"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you for solution and explanation too. I tried to draw each keyframe on paper for better understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

After using to much time, and effort i wanted to create a (simple) alternative answer using svg.

After an hour of javascript coding, I am going to post how it is so far.
I'm not satisfied with the code, since it is to complex and using quite a some javascript code to animate the color transition.

```js
var stop = document.getElementById("stop2");

var dir = false;
var amount = 1;
var pause = false;

startanim();

function fade() {
  if (amount >= 100) {
    if (amount == 150) {
      dir = true;
    }
    amount++;
  } else if (amount <= 0) {
    if (amount == -50) {
      dir = false;
    }
    amount--;
  }
  if (dir) {
    stop.setAttribute("offset", amount + "%");
    amount--;
  } else {
    stop.setAttribute("offset", amount + "%");
    amount++;
  }
}

var interval = "id";

function startanim() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    fade();
  }, 10);
}
```

```css
.handle {
  mask: url(#myMask);
}
```

```html
<svg id="burger" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop id="stop1" stop-color="black" offset="0%" />
      <stop id="stop2" stop-color="#ddd" offset="1%" />
      <stop id="stop4" stop-color="#ddd" offset="100%" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="myMask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="url(#Gradient1)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect class="handle" x="20" y="12" width="30" height="5" />
  <rect class="handle" x="20" y="25" width="30" height="5" />
  <rect class="handle" x="20" y="37" width="30" height="5" />
</svg>
```